# continuity of series of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Given that  $f_1:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$

> where $f_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(n^{2}x)}{n^2}$

The question is, i have to check the continuity of the given series of functions.but i have no idea how to solve further,should i check its uniform convergence first?please give me a hint.

please help

Thank you

Comment: Yes, I would check uniform convergence

Comment: Do you know the Weierstrass M-test? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Comment: $f_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left | \frac{x\sin(n^{2}x)}{n^2}\right|$ < $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent so the given function conveges uniformaly

Comment: now how to relate this uniform convergence  with continuity?

Answer (score 0):

The series converges uniformly to $f_1$ .

Let us define:- $ S_m : [0,1]\to \mathbb {R}$ such that
$$ S_m (x)=\sum_{n=1}^{R}\frac{x\sin(n^{2}x)}{n^2} \text{  ;  }\forall m\ge 1$$

Observe that each of $S_r$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

It is clear by  [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test)  that $S_r\to f_1$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

**Fact:-**[**Uniform limit of a continuous function is continuous**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2164692/779382).

Hence $f_1$ is continuous.

Now continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous(proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3393128/779382)). And we have $[0,1]$ which is compact.

$\therefore f_1$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.